# Regular Expression in Python using months abbreviation

Tags: python, python-re

I have several thousand lines like:

> "The sequence 1,-2,-1,2,1,-2,-1,2,... with g.f. (1-2x)/(1+x^2) has a(n) = cos(Pi*n/2)-2*sin(Pi*n/2). - *Paul Barry*, Oct 18 2004"

and I need to find the position, if any, of the date that show up as abbreviations like 'Aug 03'. For this reason I wrote a function `_find_all_positions` that takes as input a string and a date specifier from 'Jan 01' to 'Dec 31' in a for loop.

```
def _add_zero(value: int) -> str:
   """add zero to number with digits < 2"""
   value_str = str(value)
   digits = len(value_str)
   if digits < 2:
       value_str = '0' + value_str
   return value_str
    
def get_date() -> list:
    """Get dates for author(s) search, from ' Jan 01' to ' Dec 31' """
    dates = list()
    months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    for month in months:
        for day in range(1, 32):
            dates.append(' ' + month + ' ' + ParserUtilities._add_zero(day))
    return dates

def _find_all_positions(string: str, sub: str):
    """Find all occurrences of a substring in a string"""
    start = 0
    while True:
        start = string.find(sub, start)
        if start == -1:
            return
        yield start
        start += len(sub)  # use start += 1 to find overlapping matches
```

The task is quite slow and I would like to know if with `Regular Expression` it would be possible to speed up the search

Comment: instead of `_add_zero` use format strings `f" {month} {day:02d}"`

Comment: or `str(value).zfill(2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put all months in one regular expression:

```
def find_all_positions(text):
    for match in re.finditer('(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) ([012][0-9]|30|31)', text):
        yield math.start()
```

Comment: The interpreter after import math, say about math.start() "AttributeError: module 'math' has no attribute 'start'". I suppose is match.start()

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way with a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/kVmWB9/1) that looks an uppercase letter and 2 lowercase letters following it. Then a space and 2 digits are expected:

```
import calendar
import re

# first one is empty string, we slice that
months = tuple(calendar.month_abbr)[1:]  # ("Jan", "Feb", ...)

pattern = re.compile(r"[A-Z][a-z]{2} \d{2}")

result = [match.start()
          for match in re.finditer(pattern, seq)
          if match.group().startswith(months)]
```

which gives `[111]` for the string in the question. `re.finditer` looks for all possible matches and returns an iterator which, when iterated, gives a `re.Match` object whose `start` method we query to get the positions of the matches. Since `[A-Z][a-z]{2}` can match other than months, we check if the match starts with any of the motnths. `result` will be an empty list if no match is found.